# Styled component causes unwanted rerender

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have an app that looks like this

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    config: {}
  };
  submitForm(formData) {
    this.setState({
          config: newConfig(formData)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form submit={formData => this.submitForm(formData)} />
        <Body config={this.state.config} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Form(props) {
  const QueryBox = styled.div`
    background-color: #1080f2;
    padding: 1em;
  `;

  return (
    <QueryBox>
      <MyForm submit={props.submit} />
    </QueryBox>
  );
}

class MyForm extends React.Component {

  ...

}
```

Now my problem is that the styled div causes the MyForm component to rerender upon **every** state change of the `App` component.

Why is that. Is this the expected behaviour (this would make styled components unusable for me). And is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `QueryBox` will be an entirely new component for every render of `Form`. Move it outside of `Form` instead and it will work as expected.

```
const QueryBox = styled.div`
  background-color: #1080f2;
  padding: 1em;
`;

function Form(props) {
  return (
    <QueryBox>
      <MyForm submit={props.submit} />
    </QueryBox>
  );
}
```

Comment: This was perplexing! Any workarounds such that the styling remains in the same form function?

Comment: @qwertynik If you don't want to create a separate component for `QueryBox`, you could inline the styles with the [css prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css-prop).